# keyup event not triggered for escape key

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jquery-events

I have a text input field referred to as `$nameEditor`. I want to show this text field when a button is pressed, and hide it on `blur` or when the <kbd>escape</kbd> key is pressed.

Hiding the field on `blur` works every time.

Hiding the field when pressing the escape key works only the first time. Example sequence of events.

1. Press the button that `show`s the text input field.
2. Press escape - text input field `hide`s
3. Press the button that `show`s the text input field again.
4. Press escape - the `keyup` event is not triggered
5. Press any other key and the `keyup` event is triggered
6. Press escape - the text input field `hide`s

Relevant markup:

```
<button id="renameButton" title="Rename" data-icon="ui-icon-pencil">Rename</button>
<span id="assemblyNameView">Assembly Name</span>
<input id="assemblyNameEditor" style="display:none" class="ui-corner-all widget">
```

Relevant script:

```
var $renameButton = $("#renameButton");
var $nameViewer = $('#assemblyNameView');
var $nameEditor = $('#assemblyNameEditor');
    
function cancelEdit() {
  $nameEditor.hide();
  $nameViewer.show();
}
    
function initEdit() {
  $nameViewer.hide();
  $nameEditor.val($nameViewer.text()).show().select();
}
    
function commitEdit(newName) {
  // TODO: Update the structure being edited.
  $nameEditor.hide();
  $nameViewer.text(newName);
  $nameViewer.show();
}
    
$renameButton.click(initEdit);
    
$nameEditor.blur(cancelEdit);
    
$nameEditor.keyup(function(e) {
  console.log(e);
  
  if (e.keyCode === 13) {
    var newName = val();
    
    if (newName === '') {
      alert("No name specified.");
      $nameEditor.val($nameViewer.text()).select();
      e.preventDefault();
      return false;
    }
    
    commitEdit(newName);
  }
  else if (e.keyCode === 27) {
    cancelEdit();
  }
});
```

Why is the <kbd>escape</kbd> key not triggering the `keyup` event after the input box has been hidden then re-shown?

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: Good question. I was using Chrome. However, I just tested the code in IE 10 and Firefox and I get the expected/desired behavior. This seems to be a bug in Chrome. Applying King King's solution produced the expected behavior in Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to explain what's wrong here. There is a strange effect when both the button and the textbox receive focus? It's impossible in a standard UI interface. In fact when you type keys other than <kbd>ESC</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>, <kbd>Space</kbd> and maybe more ... the typed characters are shown OK in the textbox and only the textbox receives focus after that. However if you type <kbd>ESC</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>, <kbd>Space</kbd>... the keystrokes seem to affect on the button and I can even see there is some color effect on the button showing that it's currently focused. This looks like a bug indeed.

However to solve this, I tried using `focus()` explicitly appended after `.select()` and it works OK.

```
function initEdit() {
  $nameViewer.hide();
  $nameEditor.val($nameViewer.text()).show().select().focus();
}
```

### [Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/bFru4/6/)